# Why different format specifiers give different outputs with printf?

Tags: c

I wanted to know why the output of this code is 0? 
`y.beta` and `p->beta` are the same variable, so shouldn't the output be 3?

```
int main() {
    struct MyType {
        int alpha;
        double beta;
    };
    static struct MyType y;
    struct MyType *p = &y;
    y.alpha = 1;
    p->alpha = 2;
    p->beta = 2.5;
    y.beta = 1.5;
    printf("%d", y.beta + p->beta);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `%d` needs to be `%f`

Comment: thank you, why isn't %d working? @user3386109

Comment: @Nona: %d is for digits (integers), %f is for floats.

Comment: `%d` is used to print an integer, e.g. `alpha`. `%f` is used to print `float` or `double`, e.g. `beta`. Even though the number you're trying to print happens to be an integer, the expression `y.beta + p->beta` has type `double`.

Comment: The type of the value supplied needs to match the type in the format specifier.   Otherwise the result is undefined behaviour.   There is no magic in `printf()` that says something "The value passed is a double, but the format is `%d`, so only print the integral part".   So passing a floating point value to `%d`, which expects an `int`  (not a float or double) is undefined behaviour.  Similarly, passing a `float` to the `%d` format.

Comment: BTW, if you have enabled warnings in your compiler (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then you'll get a warning on `printf` and would have been able to correct your mistake without asking here

Comment: The OP's question was *why is the output 0 in this code?*, and the reason was a simple typo.  @nilanjanaLodh changed it to *Why different format specifiers give different outputs with printf?*, which is more on topic but not the OP's original intent.

Answer (score 2):

As [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) correctly pointed out, `printf("%d", somevariable)`  expects that the variable is passed as an `int`, whereas your result is a `double` type value.

`%d` is called a format specifier. These are required because different data types are passed and interpreted in different ways by the processor, possibly at a different place in memory or in different registers (as is the case for the x86_64 platform). So even the same memory location, with the same bit pattern may be interpreted very differently based on the data type. That's what is happening in this other example:

```
int main() {
    int a = 1048577;;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%hd", a);  //hd is the format specifier for short int
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 1048577 
 1
```

As you see, the same variable a is interpreted differently based on what data type you specify.

**Why is it so?**
This is the binary representation of 1048577 (assuming 32-bit `int`):

```
00000000 00010000 00000000 00000001
```

If the format specifier is `short int` (`%hd`) then is shorts are 16 bit wide, only the 16 low order bits from the value are used, hence the output is `1`.

Something similar may be happening in your case on some architectures (x86 32 bits) or something worse on other ones where the `double` value is passed in a different way and `printf` gets the `int` from a location where nothing specific was written by the caller and any random value could happen to be there, such as `0`.

The solution to this would be to modify your code to
`printf("%f", y.beta + p->beta);` as pointed out by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanations, but your example is somewhat misleading: `%hu` expects an `unsigned int` but interprets it as un `unsigned short`. This would not invoke undefined behavior, whereas `%llu` would on platforms where `sizeof(long long) != sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Corrected it to %hd. Looks alright now.

Comment: not completely.  `%hd` and `%hu` both reinterpret an `int` or `unsigned int` argument as it by casting it respectively to `short` and `unsigned short`.  In your explanation you mention *the last 8 bits* but it is really *the last 16 bits* or maybe more depending on the actual size of `short`.  Furthermore, different types may be passed in different places to `printf`, so the discussion of how bit patterns are interpreted may not be pertinent.  I corrected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You invoke undefined behavior by passing the wrong type of argument to `printf`:

```
printf("%d", y.beta + p->beta);
```

`%d` expects an `int` to be passed, `y.beta + p->beta` is a `double` value.

Change the code to:

```
printf("%f\n", y.beta + p->beta);
```

Undefined behavior means anything can happen; it is vain to try and understand why it prints `0`. Something else may happen on a different machine, or at a different time, or even if it is raining or if the boss is coming ;-)